# How to compile realm-cocoa with source code

Tags: realm

Our company's svn cannot allow single file larger than 40mb, realm framework needs 140mb+，so how can I build realm-cocoa with source code on github?

Answer (score 1):

You could instead use the dynamic framework, which is a lot smaller (28,5 MB), through being already linked, but you won't be able to support iOS 7 in that way.

Alternatively I would recommend using a dependency manager like [CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods), which helps you with the setup and integration. But as a Core Member of this project, I'm obviously biased in that regard.

If that shouldn't be available for you, then you could theoretically use SVN externals to checkout the realm-cocoa repo (GitHub supports SVN transports), add the `Realm.xcodeproj` to your Xcode project, set the `iOS` framework target as dependency target of your app target and link to `Realm.framework`. But please not that this is not an officially supported way of integration.

Comment: cocoapods can resolve my problem, but the librealm-ios.a now is 39.1Mb, I'm worry about it'll 40Mb+ someday. Hope realm-core can open source earlier.

Comment: You could ignore your `Pods` directory. See [our guides for further discussion about (dis)advantages of that](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control).